# What are incase tables in SQL

Tags: postgresql

I want to know what are incase table as given in the below query.

```
CREATE TABLE msa_xref_tb_incase
               TABLESPACE users AS
               SELECT * FROM msa_xref_tb;
```

Please solve my query.

Comment: Tables that are there "just in case"? Not a generic term I've come across...

Comment: tables that are there "just in case". if we have to build tables "just incase" we will try build views .what is the purpose of creating incase tables.

Comment: There is no such thing as an “incase table” from a technical point of view. In the query you’ve shown, someone just decided to use “incase” as part of the _table name_. So I guess if they had used “foobar” instead, you would have asked us what a “foobar table” is …?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such term as "incase tables", but the SQL statement you provided simply creates a new table (named `msa_xref_tb_incase`)  based on the output of a `select` statement.

Your statement basically "saves" the result of the query into a new table.